# jQuery - Target next element by class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm tryingto target the next div with `class="modal"` to display it when i click on the `<h4>` OR the `<div>` with class "imgdd".

```
<li class="itemmenumodal">
    <div class="imgdd"></div>
    <h4>test</h4>                       
    <div class="modal">
        <p>hello there</p>
    </div>
</li>
```

I tried this, it works when i click on the `<h4>` but not for the `<div>` with `class="imgdd"` :

```
$(".itemmenumodal h4,.itemmenumodal div.imgdd").click(function(){
    jQuery(this).next(".modal").bPopup({            
        speed: 350,
        transition: 'slideDown',
        closeClass:'closemodal',
    });                 
})
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

.next() will only get the next element therefore you must use .nextAll() and :first to get the next first .modal element

```
  jQuery(this).nextAll(".modal:first").bPopup({
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work:

```
$(".itemmenumodal h4,.itemmenumodal div.imgdd").click(function(){
    $(jQuery(this).siblings(".modal")[0]).bPopup({            
    speed: 350,
    transition: 'slideDown',
    closeClass:'closemodal',
});                 
})
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3PwHK/